# replaceWith doesn't works inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `a` like below:

```
<a id="tor" onclick="f1(this);">click to change</a>
```

Now I want to replace it with another tag like `p`. I tried this but doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function f1(tor) {
        tor.replaceWith('<p>Hello</p>');//This doesn't work
        alert(tor.id);//But this works
    }                         
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` or `tor` here is not a jQuery object, but a JavaScript HTML Element. Wrap it inside `$` to enable the jQuery functions on it:

```
function f1(tor) {
   $(tor).replaceWith('<p>Hello</p>');   // This now works.
   alert(tor.id);                        // This is basic JS, so works.
}
```

**Snippet**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="tor" onclick="f1(this);">click to change</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function f1(tor) {
    $(tor).replaceWith('<p>Hello</p>');
    alert(tor.id);
  }
</script>
```